# Installing MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Utilizing Data Array

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, installation, database-administration

Maybe I can't put together a query that finds what I am looking for on the Internet, but I want to make sure this is done right.

I have a new server that has Windows Server 2008 R2 loaded onto a RAID 1 configuration.  I need to install SQL Server 2008 R2 to take advantage of a RAID 1+0 (10) configuration I also have on this server. I understand these basics:

- Host the database (mdf) files on the data array (the RAID 10 partition)
- Host the log (ldf) files on the OS array (the RAID 1 partition)

What I need help clarifying is the actual install of SQL Server.  For example, should I place the Program Files on the data array?  Should I put the names instance on the data array?  If not, what are the best practices for the actual INSTALL of SQL Server?  The rest I can readily search through Google.

If anyone has any advice, direction, or resources here, I would really appreciate it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS partition. Performance wise this is a total non issue - SQL Server itself does VERY little IO outsid e of that the databases do.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up going with. I was more worried about the named instance because I didn't know if that will directly or negatively impact how the log and database files were located and utilized.

Comment: No, you can select those during the install process separately - no larger install keeps data and app together. Attention to tempdb, btw. - that CAN blow Performance. Make sure you size it right.

Comment: Yes, I am reading plenty of articles on it right now.  Do you have any recommended resources that you can link me to by any chance?

Comment: No. My tip would be to put temp AND LOG FILES on a ssd though - the reduced latency of the logs will possibly impact changes quite a lot, depending on your load.